# How does high order 'run' function block work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, callback

run signature looks like:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {
contract {
    callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
}
return block()
```

}

The way I see it, the callback (*block*), is being called via a receiver but **without any parameters**. So how someone (with a lot of credits here) , said me that:

1.

```
thing.run(::println)
```

is equivalent to :

2.

```
thing.run { println(this) }
```

I can't understant how the first is running at all... since the way i see it the *println* won't get any parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a function to a higher-order function by using the function reference syntax instead of a lambda, it doesn't matter if there's a receiver or not. The receiver is like any other parameter, and can be thought of as the first parameter.

So the syntax of run's function parameter:

```
T.() -> R
```

will be treated exactly the same as the syntax of let's function parameter:

```
(T) -> R
```

so `::println` can match either of these.

This works in the other direction, too. When you pass an extension function or member function using function reference syntax, the receiver of the extension function is treated as the first parameter. Either of these is valid:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
list.run(List<Int>::sum)
list.let(List<Int>::sum)
```

So whether there is a receiver or not only affects lambdas. The actual function signature is the same. You can see this issue if you try to define two functions like this. There will be a compiler error for the two functions having the same signature:

```
class Foo

fun bar(foo: Foo) {
    println("Hello")
}

fun Foo.bar() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

Comment: you are saying:`This works in the other direction, too`.. Can you please explain what it the other direction in the *list* examples?

Comment: I mean with `println`, the first parameter is matched to the receiver of `.run`'s function and conversely with `List::sum`, the receiver (list)  is matched to the first parameter of `.let`'s function.